# Reference variable at RITM

Tags: servicenow

[image]

it became read only automatically.

But if its data type is changed to Single line text then it is editable; but if its type is Reference then then it is read only.

I have checked Access Control Lists on this table and gave access to everyone by not specifying any role.

Comment: what are you referencing it to if you change the type to reference? Which table is kept as reference? May be that table is readonly.

Comment: I am admin and I tried giving different tables but the problem  persisted...